# Navigation in a Build Your Own (LWR) Community/Digital Experience

Tags: community, navigationmixin.navigate, lightning-web-runtime

I am trying to set up some links to navigate to other pages in a Salesforce Community/Digital Experience site. I have an existing LWC that used the navigation mixin to get this to work within a Build Your Own (Aura) community. However when I try this in the LWR version, I can't seem to get navigation to work. The following snippet works in the aura community and the LWC is API Version 48

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
               pageName: 'practice'
            }
            });
```

I've tried switching to the attribute of "name" instead of page name, and in there I have tried also using the api name of the page (+ __c) and I always get an Invalid Page error with this message "A URL cannot be created to navigate to route "comm__namedPage"

What is the correct way to navigate to other pages in a Build Your Own LWR community? Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between different types of pages (record, internal page, external page) and update the navigation object accordingly.

E.g. this snippet should work for any internal page

```
{
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: target
    },
    state: {
        filterName: defaultListViewId
}
```

Taken from this salesfroce [sample app](https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/navigationMenuItem/navigationMenuItem.js).

And also check out this tutorial from [salesforce](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgIMQe2PKPSJXw3x0cPTJhzNyLBgpZV5a) about how to build lwr sites.